# Mongodb calculate product stock from sales and purchase

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I was trying to build simple billing application. I have store product opening quantity, and sales and purchases along with product id. I need product wise current stock of all products on Products collection. I have created a [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_R9mH_WhFG4).

Products collection

```
[
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6499d7eb72fb2552774c9f80"),
      "name": "Product 1",
      "openingStock": 10
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6499d81a72fb2552774c9f82"),
      "name": "Product 2",
      "openingStock": 10
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6499d83d72fb2552774c9f84"),
      "name": "Product 3",
      "openingStock": 20
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6499d86e72fb2552774c9f86"),
      "name": "Product 4",
      "openingStock": 15
    }, 
  ]
```

Sales Collection

```
[
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("64a559f68d79acbc66d96fdf"),
      "products": [
        {
          "product": ObjectId("6499d7eb72fb2552774c9f80"),
          "qty": 3
        },
        {
          "product": ObjectId("6499d83d72fb2552774c9f84"),
          "qty": 3
        },
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("64a559da8d79acbc66d96fde"),
      "products": [
        {
          "product": ObjectId("6499d7eb72fb2552774c9f80"),
          "qty": 3
        },
        {
          "product": ObjectId("6499d83d72fb2552774c9f84"),
          "qty": 1.5
        },
        
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Purchase Collection

```
[
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("64a5b540ffcbb3b942ccaae8"),
      "products": [
        {
          "product": ObjectId("6499d81a72fb2552774c9f82"),
          "qty": 2
        },
        {
          "product": ObjectId("6499d7eb72fb2552774c9f80"),
          "qty": 3.3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

My expected result looks like bellow.

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6499d7eb72fb2552774c9f80"),
    "name": "Product 1",
    "stock": 7.3
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6499d81a72fb2552774c9f82"),
    "name": "Product 2",
    "stock": 12
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6499d83d72fb2552774c9f84"),
    "name": "Product 3",
    "stock": 15.5
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6499d86e72fb2552774c9f86"),
    "name": "Product 4",
    "stock": 15
  }
]
```

Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: What is what you want to achieve? Could you add an expected output?

Comment: My expected result is added. @RubénVega

Comment: So you want your initial stock minus sales plus purchased right?

Comment: Yes. @RubénVega

Comment: Hope my answer help you!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to join your 3 collections, using 2 `lookup` with some pipelines to `unwind` the `sales` and `purchases` collection. The reason for this is that we only need to merge the individual products and not the whole sale.

Once this is done, we would apply `sum` and `subtract` to the joined arrays and the initial field.

[Mongoplayground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rrCM4hFS6si)

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "sales",
      "let": {
        "id": "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$unwind": "$products"
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              "$eq": [
                "$products.product",
                "$$id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "sales"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "purchase",
      "let": {
        "id": "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$unwind": "$products"
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              "$eq": [
                "$products.product",
                "$$id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "purchases"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "finalStock": {
        $sum: [
          {
            "$subtract": [
              "$openingStock",
              {
                "$sum": [
                  "$sales.products.qty",
                  
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "$sum": [
              "$purchases.products.qty",
              
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      finalStock: 1
    }
  }
])
```